# Why does Nvidia Settings have different resolutions than the Monitor option?

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, resolution

I checked the resolutions in **System -> Preferences -> Monitors** and it has different resolutions than the **System -> Administration -> Nvidia X Server Settings**

I have installed the proprietary Nvidia Drivers from the Additional Drivers options (jockey-gtk) version 270.41.06

Now my question is why the difference and how can i (if possible) make them the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the Monitors capplet uses the `XRandR` protocol to do multi-monitor and resolution changes.  The proprietary nvidia drivers only support an old and restrictive version of this protocol, so it's entirely possible to have a system where the information the Monitors capplet gets from the nvidia driver is different from the information that the NVidia Settings (which uses an nvidia-specific protocol to talk to the driver) gets.

This means that there are two options for making the resolutions displayed the same:

- Add code to the Monitors capplet to talk the nvidia-specific protocol to the nvidia driver (as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13636/how-do-we-get-nvidia-to-make-nvidia-settings-a-less-terrible-piece-of-software))
- Have nvidia implement more modern `XRandR` support in their driver, so the nvidia driver can expose the relevant information in the same way that all the other drivers do.

Neither of which is likely to be *immediately* useful to you, sorry.  Just use nvidia-settings for now.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a tool called Disper: [disper on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/disper)

Disper was developed to switch between internal an external screens, because xrandr is not supported by the propietary NVIDIA-drvers. (Xrandr even can't detect my displays).

Also you can set screen resolutions with disper:
Hope, that this may help.

```
    disper --help
Usage: disper [options] (-l|-s|-c|-e|-p|-i)

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         show what's happening
  -q, --quiet           be quiet and only show errors
  -r RESOLUTION, --resolution=RESOLUTION
                        set resolution, e.g. "800x600", or "auto" to detect
                        the display's preferred resolution, or "max" to use
                        the maximum resolution advertised. For extend it is
                        possible to enter a single resolution for all displays
                        or a comma-separated list of resolutions (one for each
                        display). Beware that many displays advertise
                        resolutions they can not fully show, so "max" is not
                        advised.
  -d DISPLAYS, --displays=DISPLAYS
                        comma-separated list of displays to operate on, or
                        "auto" to detect; the first is the primary display.
  -t DIRECTION, --direction=DIRECTION
                        where to extend displays: "left", "right", "top", or
                        "bottom"
  --scaling=SCALING     flat-panel scaling mode: "default", "native",
                        "scaled", "centered", or "aspect-scaled"
  --plugins=PLUGINS     comma-separated list of plugins to enable. Special
                        names: "user" for all user plugins in ~/.disper/hooks;
                        "all" for all plugins found; "none" for no plugins.
  --cycle-stages=CYCLE_STAGES
                        colon-separated list command-line arguments to cycle
                        through

  Actions:
    Select exactly one of the following actions

    -l, --list          list the attached displays
    -s, --single        only enable the primary display
    -S, --secondary     only enable the secondary display
    -c, --clone         clone displays
    -e, --extend        extend displays
    -p, --export        export current settings to standard output
    -i, --import        import current settings from standard input
    -C, --cycle         cycle through the list of cycle stages
```