# 12.04.2 Nvidia driver issue?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I just installed 12.04.2 and I'm stuck with 1024x768 resolution on my GTX560.
Impossible to change the resolution; the native resolution (1680x1050) is not detected.
Any clue ?
Thanks.

The additional drivers panel doesn't show any driver to install, so I kept the original driver.
Here is the xrandr output anyway:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 430mm x 270mm
   1024x768       75.0*+   60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Have you already installed the proprietary driver through "Additional drivers"? If yes please press Ctrl-Alt-t, in the terminal type: `xrandr`. Edit your question and post `xrandr` output.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. We should install the driver first. In the terminal run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

enter your password (you won't see anything as you type it, don't worry) and confirm adding the repository. It contains the latest drivers.

update repos

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now let's install the driver, still in the term

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-313 nvidia-settings
```

You will have to reboot. Report back

---

*Driver activated but not in use problem*

Never seen that before. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

then

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

logout and login again

Comment: It does not work :

Comment: Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 nvidia-current : Dépend: xorg-video-abi-11
                  Dépend: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».

Comment: Sorry, I have a french version, so I will translate:

Comment: The following packets contain non satisfied dependencies: nvidia-current Impossible to correct issues, the failing packets are in state "keep in state"

Comment: Aucun probleme mon ami. On s'entend bien. I updated my answer, as Luis Alvarado pointed out a better repository and a more recent driver. Just repeat the 3 steps in my answer again.

Comment: Thanks a lot phipsalabim and Luis, the installation of nvidia-313 went fine (I think), after reboot, the driver is stated as activated but not in use inside the "Proprietary drivers" panel; how can I force the use of this driver ?

Comment: if it says activated it means it's being used. Everything is fine. Just confusing semantics. Is the resolution ok now?

Comment: No, that's why I mentioned the "not in use" statement, still cannot change the resolution and still not automatically detected

Comment: xrandr output :

Comment: Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 430mm x 270mm
   1024x768       75.0*+   60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: "Aucun pilote propriétaire n'est utilisé sur ce système"

Comment: Thanks, after using those following commands, the 1680x1050 resolution is automatically detected. Still no proprietary driver in use, but it satisfies my needs for the moment.
Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Nvidia card model so here are the links that will get you through several possible problems you might get on 12.04 related to that card:

[HDMI/VGA connection cuts borders of screen or creates blurry text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80324/hdmi-vga-connection-cuts-borders-of-screen-or-creates-blurry-text-unfocused-for)
(This is just in case you get the top/bottom parts of the screen cut out)

[Enable HDMI audio for an Nvidia card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54999/enable-hdmi-audio-on-nvidia-gtx470/104172#104172)
(This is so you know about the HDMI Audio)

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/newest-nvidia-card-what-driver-should-i-install/61433#61433)
(**RECOMMENDED LINK** - Recommended way of installing the drivers for you. This will also fix other problems you might encounter with a high end video card like the one you and I have.)

[Difference between Additional Drivers (Nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216286/difference-between-additional-drivers-nvidia/218181#218181)
(So you know the difference between all of drivers found in Ubuntu related to this card. I would again recommend using the above link to install the latest driver)

[Why does Nvidia Settings have different resolutions than the Monitor option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43738/why-does-nvidia-settings-have-different-resolutions-than-the-monitor-option)
(Reasons why the resolution can be different that what is advertised when using a PC and a TV Monitor)

In your case, use the **nvidia-313** driver found in the Xorg Edgers PPA which I mention in the link I recommend above.